# Fading CurveVertex() trails using background opacity value not working

Tags: java, processing, rendering

Using FX2D.

Hi, I'm currently drawing a line at every frame using the curveVertex() function.
Every line stays on the sketch voluntarily by not resetting the background at every step,
which leaves a trail effect.

But I would like to make these trails fade away over time. I tried resetting the background in the draw() function by giving it a small opacity value but it clears all the trails at once every time.

Right now I can only have either all trails or no trails.

```
  //background(0, 0, 0, 10); // Reset background every time
  stroke(255, 255, 255, 10); // Draw Line between all nodes
  curveVertex(nodes.get(fixId(i)).position.x, nodes.get(fixId(i)).position.y);
```

[with trails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUha2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`background()`](https://processing.org/reference/background_.html) does not just set the background color, it clear the entire window. It is not intended to use `background` within [`beginShape()` / `endShape()`](https://processing.org/reference/beginShape_.html) sequences.

What what to do can be achieved by drawing a [`rect()`](https://processing.org/reference/rect_.html) with [`blendMode(DIFFERENCE)`](https://processing.org/reference/blendMode_.html) on the entire window, at the begin of the frame. e.g.:

```java
void draw() {

    // "fade" the entire view 
    blendMode(DIFFERENCE);
    fill(1, 1, 1, 255);
    rect(0, 0, width, height);

    blendMode(ADD);

    // draw shape
    // [...]

}
```

---

<sub>See also the answer to [Processing - rendering shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52281399/processing-rendering-shapes-is-too-slow/52282274#52282274).</sub>